# OData service without WCF data services

Tags: wcf, rest, odata

Is it possible to create an OData compliant RESTful web service on an MS platform without using WCF data services?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can comply with the spec using plain old asp.net.  Its way more work though.  Why would you do this?

Comment: this is more of a comment than an answer

Comment: It was a yes\no question.  The answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and since time has passed since you originally asked the question it is now easier to create an OData Service without using WCF Data Services as you can use the ASP.NET Web API which can provide (somewhat limited) OData functionality when you expose IQueryable methods.

http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.webapi.odata